# 100% width Header. Want the centre element to be the only thing that shrinks

Tags: css

hi see the image for the best describer of what i really need. im only starting out in css. i feel im close to the solution.

its a header bar that fills the width of the screen. when the screen shrinks element 2 in the image should be the only thing that shrinks as it will have no content. The other elements i'd like as a fixed 200px to fit in input boxes

my code so far:

```
* {
border: 0px dashed blue;
}

div {
height: 150px;
width: 15%;
border: 0px solid black;
border-radius: 0px;
display: inline-block;

}

#one {
background-color: #FF0000;
width: 150px
}

#two {
background-color: #0000FF;
width: 50%; 
}

#three {
background-color: #FFD700;
width: 200px;

}

#four {
background-color: #308014;
width: 200px;
}

#five {
background-color: pink;
width: 100px;
}

#WAYText {
background-color: purple;
display: block;
height: 25%;
width: 200px;
}

#WAYInput {
background-color: cyan;
display: block;
height: 25%;
width: 200px;
}

#SearchText {
background-color: purple;
display: block;
height: 25%;
width: 200px;
}

#SearchInput {
background-color: cyan;
display: block;
height: 25%;
width: 200px;
}

#HowText {
background-color: purple;
display: block;
height: 25%;
width: 200px;
}

#HowInput {
background-color: cyan;
display: block;
height: 25%;
width: 200px;
}

#DateText {
background-color: purple;
display: block;
height: 25%;
width: 200px;
}

#DateInput {
background-color: cyan;
display: block;
height: 25%;
width: 200px;
}
```

and the html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    <title>Result</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
    <div id="three">
        <div id="WAYText"></div>
        <div id="WAYInput"></div>
        <div id="SearchText"></div>
        <div id="SearchInput"></div>
       </div>
    <div id="four">
        <div id="HowText"></div>
        <div id="HowInput"></div>
        <div id="DateText"></div>
        <div id="DateInput"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="five"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image for what i want it do act like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaYbQ.jpg)

Comment: Depending on your browser support, take a look at Flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ . This layout should be possible using the 'Flex-grow' method mentioned on this page. (Edit: Or flex-shrink might be the one :) )

Comment: right i think i've done it - i used a container to hold everything - deleted element 2 and floated the other elements to the right side. i did look at flexbox but the browser compat concerns me! thanks anyway - it looks very powerful for the future!

Comment: I have another idea for this but cant really get to a fiddle right now (at work!) - if youve solved it then brilliant :)